# 'list' object has no attribute 'board'

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
class tictactoe:
    def __init__(self):  # created the self.board
        # self.board list 3x3
        self.board = [['', '', ''],
                      ['', '', ''],
                      ['', '', '']]

    def empty_places(self):  # empty places in board
        empty = []
        for i in range(3):
            for j in range(3):
                if self.board[i][j] == '': #LINE WITH THE PROBLEM
                    empty.append([i, j])
        return empty


    def game(self): 
        isTie = ai.is_tie(self.board)
        print(isTie)

class ai:
    def is_tie(board):
        isTie = False
        if len(tictactoe.empty_places(board)) == 0:
            isTie = True
        return isTie

myGame = tictactoe()
myGame.game()
```

edit: hope this gives you more information.

when i try to run this i get the error.

```
'list' object has no attribute 'board'
```

in the fourth line of def empty_places

what am i doing wrong?

Comment: There is nothing wrong with the code you shared. You are sharing the wrong code / The error comes from another code

Comment: Is this not actually inside a `class` definition?

Comment: @Gal - share every line of code you have in your python module

Comment: @balderman that is not a good advice. We don't need the whole code - just a [mre] of it

Comment: @Tomerikoo since the OP is not able to point to the problem I am not sure he will be able to create minimal example..

Comment: Right, i'll add more information in a moment.

Comment: unrelated: your code is a bit messy overall and you should consider refactoring/restructuring it.

Comment: Thank you, you two were right. thanks for helping me with my problem.

Comment: are you following the tutorial on the getting strted page of the react website

Answer (score 0):

The problem was on the class ai on def is_tie.

instead of  `if len(tictactoe.empty_places(board)) == 0: # trying to check if the list was empty`

it should be `if tictactoe.empty_places == [] :`

Thanks for everyone that helped.

Comment: nope, that wouldn't make sense. `tictactoe.empty_places` is a method (`callable` object). so that if statement would always be `False`. Eventhough, you wouldn't encounter an `Exception` the program won't behave as you may expect it to. (logical error)

Comment: I'll check it again. though im pretty sure this did work.

Comment: That is not correct Gal. `tictactoe.empty_places` is just a function object, not a **call**. So it will **always be different than an empty list**. Please see my answer for detailed explanation

Answer (score 0):

It is not clear what is the purpose of the `ai` class. The only **instance** method it has, `is_tie` is taking a `board` list as an argument. This is already un-conventional as instance methods should [usually have the first argument as `self`](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html#random-remarks) and that argument should actually be of that class.

Then you pass on the `board` list back to `empty_places` which again, expects to get a `tictactoe` object.

One way to overcome this, keeping with the `ai` class, is to make `is_tie` a [`classmethod`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#classmethod) which takes a `tictactoe` object:

```py
class ai:
    @classmethod
    def is_tie(cls, game):
        return len(game.empty_places()) == 0
```

And then you would call it as `isTie = ai.is_tie(self)` in the `game` method.

---

But then the whole `ai` class becomes a bit irrelevant and it looks like the `is_tie` method can be a `tictactoe` method instead:

```py
class tictactoe:
    def __init__(self):  # created the self.board
        # self.board list 3x3
        self.board = [['', '', ''],
                      ['', '', ''],
                      ['', '', '']]

    def empty_places(self):  # empty places in board
        empty = []
        for i in range(3):
            for j in range(3):
                if self.board[i][j] == '':
                    empty.append([i, j])
        return empty

    def is_tie(self):
        return len(self.empty_places()) == 0

    def game(self): 
        isTie = self.is_tie()
        print(isTie)
```

Answer (score -1):

```
class tictactoe:
    def __init__(self, ):  # created the self.board
        # self.board list 3x3
        self.board = [['', '', ''],
                      ['', '', ''],
                      ['', '', '']]

    def empty_places(self):  # empty places in board
        empty = []
        for i in range(3):
            for j in range(3):
                if self.board[i][j] == '': #LINE WITH THE PROBLEM
                    empty.append("done")
        return empty

tic = tictactoe()

print(tic.empty_places())
```

Output:
['done', 'done', 'done', 'done', 'done', 'done', 'done', 'done', 'done']

Answer (score -1):

I tried runnning your code but I didn't get any errors, it seems to work fine:

```
##### your code
class tictactoe:
    def __init__(self):  # created the self.board
        # self.board list 3x3
        self.board = [['', '', ''],
                      ['', '', ''],
                      ['', '', '']]

    def empty_places(self):  # empty places in board
        empty = []
        for i in range(3):
            for j in range(3):
                if self.board[i][j] == '': #LINE WITH THE PROBLEM
                    empty.append([i, j])
        return empty
 
#### What I added  
# create a board object
board = tictactoe()

# check for empty places
empty_places_list = board.empty_places()

# print the list with empty spaces
print(empty_places_list)
```

If I run the code above. the following is printed

```
[[0, 0], [0, 1], [0, 2], [1, 0], [1, 1], [1, 2], [2, 0], [2, 1], [2, 2]]
```

I tried running it on IDLE and in Spyder, with Python 3.7.Maybe this already helps you somehow, otherwise I would suggest providing more context or more info on how/where you are running your code.